# Indentation error in Django Unit Testing

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I'm using unit tests for my Django project. I created the code below in test.py

```
from django.test import TestCase
from login.models import CustomUser
from django.utils import timezone
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse


class LoginTest(TestCase):

def create_user(self, username = "test", password = "12345", emailadd = "testing101@testing101.com", user_privileges = 1, firstname = "Test", lastname = "Culinary"):
        return CustomUser.objects.create(username=username,password=password,emailadd=emailadd, user_privileges=user_privileges, firstname=firstname, lastname=lastname)

def test(self):
    w = self.create_user()
    self.assertTrue(isinstance(w, Whatever))
    self.assertEqual(w.__unicode__(), w.username)
```

But when I enter
python manage.py test in the terminal, it displays:

```
File "/Users/pshsssip/devproj/rrs/login/models.py", line 10
def create_user(self, username, password, emailadd, user_privileges):
                                                                    ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

What could be the problem here? :)

Comment: are you mixing tabs and spaces? some text editors won't display that properly but you won't have consistent indentation

Answer (score 1):

The `create_user` function needs to be indented so it is inside the `LoginTest` class.

Answer (score 1):

When in classes, everything inside has to be indented. Your functions `create_user()` and `test()` are both not indented. Instead, try the following code:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from login.models import CustomUser
from django.utils import timezone
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse


class LoginTest(TestCase):

    def create_user(self, username = "test", password = "12345", emailadd = "testing101@testing101.com", user_privileges = 1, firstname = "Test", lastname = "Culinary"):
        return CustomUser.objects.create(username=username,password=password,emailadd=emailadd, user_privileges=user_privileges, firstname=firstname, lastname=lastname)

    def test(self):
        w = self.create_user()
        self.assertTrue(isinstance(w, Whatever))
        self.assertEqual(w.__unicode__(), w.username)
```